# installing ubuntu on toshiba satellite

Tags: drivers, toshiba-satellite

I'm using Ubuntu since few month(january 2013) and I'm still a beginner.
I want to know if is it possible to install any version of ubuntu on my new toshiba satellite pro L830 15K and if there will be any problem of compatibility.
I put a link with the features of that machine.

http://www.toshiba.eu/laptops/satellite-pro/l830/satellite-pro-l830-15k/

Comment: Have fun. You can run any version of Ubuntu you want on a Toshiba Satellite Pro L830-15K laptop.

Comment: I still have doubts because the technician who tried to install the 12.04 LTS for me (I asked him just beacuse I was in a hurry) said that it has some problems with the vga, so he rebooted the machine with windows and I will do that on my own...any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run any version of Ubuntu you want on a Toshiba Satellite Pro L830-15K laptop.

In order to install the correct graphics driver for your laptop, open the Ubuntu Software Center and search for *ATI binary X.Org driver*. You can find this package the easy way if you just search for *amd*. From the ATI binary X.Org driver description in the Ubuntu Software Center:

*"Video driver for the AMD Radeon and the FireGL graphics accelerators. This package provides 2D display drivers and hardware accelerated OpenGL."*

From my own personal experience on hardware similar to yours, I would say that you should expect splendid graphics performance from the ATI binary X.Org driver. There are also slightly more up-to-date versions of the same driver available at the AMD website, but I stuck with the ATI binary X.Org driver package that I installed from the default Ubuntu repositories, and I have never had any problems with it.

Comment: ok, now it works perfectly!!! thank you very much!!!!

Comment: just a tip: before installing the drivers I had to go on the boot setting (pressing "e" in the grub menu while highlightening ubuntu) and write "nomodeset_$vt_handoff" instead "quiet splash vt_handoff", then I could go into ubuntu and install the ATI drivers

Comment: I just booted straight into the desktop, installed the ATI driver and then rebooted. However I also have an AMD processor.

Answer (score 2):

You can check these sites for your machine :

- [Linux Hardware Compatibility Lists & Linux Drivers](http://www.linux-drivers.org/)
- [Linux on Laptops](http://www.linux-laptop.net/)

You should also check this [similar question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/16520/how-to-know-what-hardware-works-well-with-linux#16522).